# In VSCode, how can I select current element and it"s surroundings like in WebStorm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

In WebStorm you can select an element and it's surrounding when you do <kbd>Alt + Arrow Up</kbd>.

How can you achieve that in VSCode ?

Comment: What do you mean *"it's surrounding"*?

Comment: If, by "surrounding", you mean increasing scope, see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region .  Expand region scope extension, works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with VSCode buit in `Emmet: Balance (outward)` command: `Ctrl+Shift+A`

If the shortcut does not work, follow these steps:

- Press `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open the Command Palette
- Type `Emmet`
- Select `Emmet: Balance (outward)`

This will select the tag where you have your cursor currently in, and all its contents (I understand that by *its surroundings* you mean the tag contents and the tag itself).

If the tag has as a content a combination of text and tags and your cursor is in the text, the command will select all the content. A new hit of the command will grow the selection to include the tag itself.